# What is the Vout of 74154 demux and 7404 hex inverter?

Tags: inverter, ttl, decoder

I've read through the datasheet of 74154 and have seen that its Vout ranges from 0.5V to Vcc+0.5V. So if the Vcc is 5V, I am assuming I can get 5.5V max Vout in the output pins. However, a friend of mine said that since 74154 is TTL, its Vout is about 2.5V to 3.5V; tho she did not mention if this is during ACTIVE HIGH or ACTIVE LOW.

My question being: in practice, how much really is the Vout of a 74154 demux during its ACTIVE LOW and during its ACTIVE HIGH at one output instance (say, with an 0000 input that gives an output of ACTIVE LOW at pin 1 and ACTIVE HIGH at all other pins)?

I have the same question as per the 7404 IC.

Can someone help? :) Thank you!

Comment: There are lots of varieties of 74154 and 7404 -- original 7400 TTL series, LS (e.g. 74LS154), HC, HCT etc.  Please provide link to the datasheet.  Active high level Vout for a TTL gate is typically around 3.4v, active low a little above ground, maybe 0.2v.  The low level *input* threshold is around 0.8v.  The high level *input* threshold is perhaps 2v, so these active high and low Vout levels are above and below the input thresholds.

Comment: Link to datasheet is missing.

Comment: You'd mentioned you want to continue using the part you have, in an earlier post. What exactly _do_ you have? The original 74154 (I have some here) come from the early to mid 1970's. Since then there have been a variety of _improvements_ for different purposes. Some, to varying degrees, incompatible with each other, too. Since you have the part, what is the exact part-designation found on the top side of the part? (Date code might be interesting too, if you can find it.) Can you photograph the part and include the picture? (The above applies to your 7404, as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking at the Absolute Maximum ratings, rather than Operating Characteristics. 5.5 volts is the maximum voltage that can be be applied to an output (or any) pin without damaging the IC.

For the 7404, the Operating Characteristics table shows the minimum Voh (output high voltage) is 2.4 volts, and typical is 3.5 volts when sourcing 0.4 mA.

Vol (Output Low voltage) is 0.2 V typical to 0.4V maximum when sinking 16 mA.

Answer (score 0):

This takes an understanding in Transmission Line Theory for full appreciation. But basically is not a problem for good layouts just a protection of reverse Vbe voltages on high speed bipolar devices for overshoot on "1" input.

CMOS is worse as it has SCR latchup issues from overshoot but protected by internal 2stage diode, series 10k clamps on all inputs to9 both rails.

**5.5V refers to Vin from overshoot not Vout capability**

However Vout of the NPN,PNP push-pull drivers and asymmetrical impedance load can generate this voltage along the track. V=LdI/dt and I=CdV/dt both in effect here.

(CMOS is not immune to this problem as it always has high R input with small pF)

This only occurs when the Tprop delay of the track > Trise time causing overshoot.  Controlled impedance tracks significantly reduce this effect ( i.e. lower Zo with wider tracks or smaller gap to ground plane.

> typically w/g = 0.5 to 1 of signal track as this affects impedance in 50~100R range.

Study of transmission lines is needed to understand principles of overshoot from distributed L,C of tracks where Z of track depends on width to gap ratio to ground for any length in nH/cm and pF/cm.

[image]
[image] transmission Line nH/cm and pF/cm
[image]  ref http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3854/en/ for further reading

Comment: Does anyone care this  is the reason for the 5.5V? or just not understand what I said?

Comment: Since you're asking, put me in the "not understand" category :-) Specifically, I think you're saying that exceeding 5.5V on an input exceeds the reverse Vbe limit on the input transistor. But the input transistor's base is near Vcc, so the reverse voltage is pretty small. Also shouldn't the limit depend on Vcc, since with a low Vcc, Vbe would be bigger? Or is the input protection diode what will fail?

Comment: Hi @KenShirriff  No. We're talking Standard TTL 74154,  here and the diagram shows the base with a 6k pullup and the collector is tied to 2 diodes to ground making Vb= 3 diode drops above ground or 2.1V thus 5.5V (The Absolute Maximum) in causes Vbe=  2.1-5.5 = -3.4V . For whatever other reason 5.5V is the max input caused by line inductance that I hand sketched between output and input and mismatched Z.  Two diode drops is in fact the input Threshold voltage for all TTL families (74,74S,74L,74LS) except CMOS where HCT is closer to 1.5V

Comment: I guess no one else here actually mastered 74' TTL. I remember damaging TTL in my 1st job thinking it was ESD later (circa 75) perhaps it was long breadboard leads and overvoltage on input..